# How to build a flash game to Android?

Tags: android, air, flash-cs5

I have a .fla game and your respective .swf, I want to convert the swf to run on a Android Tablet or smartphone, I took a look on some answers, but I can't find an actual way to build the swf to Android using Adobe Flash CS5 professional, What I need to do ? I have de Android SDK, but don't have any idea, I saw that can be made with Adobe Air, but I dont understood =/

Sorry, I'm newbie on Android Devices.

Thanks.

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/06/no-flash-for-android-4-1-no-new-installs-after-august-15/

Comment: So I can use only Eclipse with Android SDK plugin ? =/

Comment: I think the takeaway is that the future is HTML5.

Comment: You take the game and build it. That's it.

Comment: Have a look at this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd4Wkv0dXiE